# Emscripten - Compile to WASM and keep original callable function names in the glue code

Tags: javascript, emscripten, webassembly

Using Emscripten v 1.38.43, I'm compiling a C code. For optimization reasons, I've stripped down the generated JS glue code and minimize the code size.

While doing so I've spotted that the JS callables are mapped like so:

```
var asmLibraryArg = {
  "b": ___setErrNo,
  "j": _emscripten_get_heap_size,
  "i": _emscripten_memcpy_big,
  "h": _emscripten_resize_heap,
  "g": myFunctionA,
  "f": myFunctionB,
  "e": myFunctionC,
  "d": myFunctionD,
  "c": abortOnCannotGrowMemory,
  "a": DYNAMICTOP_PTR
};
```

Making my stripped JS harder to maintain. On an older version (1.38.8) it used to output the function names with a prefixed _ i.e `"_myFunctionA" : myFunctionA`

---

**Q:** Can I give the emcc compiler a flag that will force it to keep my original function names in the generated JS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a specific flag to turn that off, but currently the internal flag `-s EMITTING_JS=0` will do that (if it thinks it isn't emitting JS, it won't minify stuff that involves JS). However, this flag may change in the future - we are working on better flags to control all this.

A workaround is to use a lower optimization level, as this is only done in `-O3`, `-Os` and above.

Answer (score 0):

use -g1 and add -O2 to link options, e.g.:

```
add_link_options("$<$<CONFIG:RELEASE>:-O2>")
```